# Hints for two proofs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

Please do not give me the answers. I only want hints to approach these two proof problems I'm struggling with:

1. There exists some differentiable function $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)\ne f(x)$ but $f''(x)=f(x)$
2. There exists some $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $x^2\in \mathbb \{R -\mathbb Q\}$ while $x^4\in \mathbb R$

For the first one I started out defining $f'$ as a limit but I couldn't come up with any way to utilize this for my proof. For the second one I've tried doing it by cases, considering $x<0, x=0, x>0$. But I didn't get anywhere doing this.

Comment: 1. Think of trigonometric functions.  2. Let $y=x^2$ and answer the analogous problem.

Comment: 1. Think exponentials and functions built from exponentials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint.

1. Solve the differential equation $y''=y$ and choose those such that $y'\ne y$.
2. Play with $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$1.$ Think about $\sin \alpha$;

$2.$ Think about $x^2=\sqrt{3}$.